# Can't log in to the Snap store?

Tags: login, snap

I am trying to remove mysql-workbench-community because apparmor will not let it log into a database.
But I get a Dialog box asking me to Log in to the Snap store. How can I find my Username and reset my password?

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need to login to the snap store to remove a snap. Open a terminal and run `sudo snap remove mysql-workbench-community`. That shouldn't require anything other than your normal desktop password to authenticate with the `sudo` command.

Comment: Yes, that works. But MYSQL Workbench not having privilege to open MYSQL ia a deal breaker for using MYSQL. Apparmor seems to be protecting me.

Comment: Maybe you should have asked that question?